# Meteor - Create Polls - Database Update

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor to create a web app that allows users to create and vote on polls.

Currently I am trying to get a user to be able to vote on a poll, but I am having no luck. This is my current method:

```
Template.PollParticipate.events({
    'click .vote': function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var target = $(event.target);

        var pollID = $(this).parent('.poll-card').data('id');
        var voteID = $(this).data('id');

        var voteString = 'options.' + voteID + '.votes';
        var action = {};
        action[voteString] = 1;

        Polls.update(
            {_id: pollID},
            {$inc: action}
        );
    }
});
```

This is the template html:

```
<template name="PollParticipate">
    <div class="poll-card text-center" data-id="{{ _id }}">
        <h3>{{question}}</h3>
        <form>
            <div>
                {{#each options}}
                    <input type="radio" name="option" value={{option}} data-id="{{ _index }}">{{option}}
                {{/each}} 
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="vote">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

In this case when a user clicks on the vote button the method would look for the id of the parent and store it in a variable. It would also try and find the index of the element selected (using radio buttons). and then pass that so that the vote counter is updated by one.

This is unfortunately not happening.

Code to whole project can be found: https://github.com/smeloa/fcc-voting-app

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a Meteor event handler, `this` is the data context where the event took place, not the DOM element, so the jQuery `$(this)` convention will not work. (The event took place from the submit button, so `this` is the poll object.) This does simplify matters, though - since the event handler has access to the data context, you can get the poll ID as `this._id` without need for a data attribute.

If you add a second parameter `template` to your event handler:

```
"click .vote": function (event, template) {
    // ...
}
```

then `template.$` is a version of the jQuery `$` which only selects elements inside the template's DOM. In that way, you can get the selected radio button with:

```
template.$("input:checked")
```

Then you can use the jQuery methods to identify that option.

You'll also want to use a method for voting rather than direct database manipulation from the client. Right now, with your current set of `allow` rules, anyone can set the votes of each option to whatever they want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will look at implementing it. Yes I am currently leaving it open while I test it, but will create a Method.call after I get it working.